# How is reversible expansion work a state function?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Work, as we know, is a path function. But between given initial and final states, there can be only be one reversible path. Is this true? If yes, then is reversible expansion work a state function? Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: A state function must be a function of a state, regardless of a path.

Comment: An expansion work, reversible or not, Is not a state function, because it depends on another state, the initial or the final state to where the expansion is carried out.

Answer (score 3):

Given the initial and final states, it is **not true** that there can be only one reversible path.  There are an infinite number of reversible paths, and they have different amounts of reversible work (and heat).  But the difference between the reversible heat and the reversible work is the same for all the reversible paths.